# Insert html elements using Django

Tags: django

Im new to Django.

So, I am getting values from our CMS which is throwing me an ordered list output.

[cms sample input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utzsM.png)

using "{{article.introtext}}" gives me this output.

```
<ol>
  <li>item number 1</li>
  <li>item number 2</li>
  <li>item number 3</li>
</ol>
```

Is there a way to manipulate or add an element in the li before being displayed using **Django**. Like below.

```
<ol>
  <li><div>inserted element</div>item number 1</li>
  <li><div>inserted element</div>item number 2</li>
  <li><div>inserted element</div>item number 3</li>
</ol>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes there are ways to insert elements, but you question is not very clear, care to explain in detail ?

Comment: How are you _getting_ those values from your CMS? Is that a Python string? If yes, you can use simple string substitution on the server side.

Comment: please upload detail code from CMS like making that text